# Measuring Memory used by a dict in Erlang

Tags: memory, dictionary, erlang

To get the item count and memory usage of an ets table, T; we may use

`ets:info(T,size)` & `ets:info(T,memory)` respectively.

Similarly, `dict:size(D)` gives the item count for a dict, D.

How can we determine the amount of memory used by a dict ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dict is normal Erlang term so it is stored in process heap and is object of garbage collection. You will be usually more concerned about process memory usage than dict itself. You can determine memory usage using `erlang:process_info/2`. If you will be still interested in size occupied by dict term you can use `erts_debug:size/1` and if you would like to know memory used when send as message `erts_debug:flat_size/1`. Note both functions returns size in words so multiple by 4 or 8 bytes depending on used VM. (i.e 32 or 64 bit VM, use `erlang:system_info(wordsize)`)

Comment: It takes a while for it to sink in that most data structures are ultimately just Erlang Terms. Thanks